# How to assign named groups in a regex to local variables

Tags: ruby, regex, capturing-group

I am trying to assign named groups of my regex expression matches to local variables. For example, I am trying to capture a string for a date input and refer to the named group `month` and `day` as local variables:

```
input = "2015-01-24" 
expr = /\d{4}-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})/ 
input =~ expr #=> 0
```

However, `month` or `day` are undefined variables after the match. How do I access `month` and `day` as local variables?

According to the [Ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html), typing the group variable name would return the captured value ("dollars" in this example)

```
/\$(?<dollars>\d+)\.(?<cents>\d+)/ =~ "$3.67" #=> 0 
dollars #=> "3"
```

I'd appreciate any recommended resources as well.

Answer (score 6):

Read more carefully the document that you cited:

> When named capture groups are used with a literal regexp on the left-hand side of an expression and the =~ operator, the captured text is also assigned to local variables with corresponding names.

Your code:

```
input =~ expr
```

does not confirm to this in two respects: (1) `expr` is not a literal regexp but is a regex assigned to a variable, (2) you have the regex on the right hand side.

If you follow the document, then you can refer to the captures as local variables.

Comment: OP: that is, `/\d{4}-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})/ =~ "2015-01-24"
 #=> 0; month #=> "01";  day #=> "24"`.  That's a literal on the left, as opposed to a variable.  Thanks, sawa, the assignments to local variables was new to me.